# An injective map between two sets of the same cardinality is bijective.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ and $F$ be finite sets. If $card(E)=card(F)\not = 0$ then an injective map from $E$ to $F$ must be bijective. I'm asking why we single out the case of the cardinalities are different from zero?

Comment: @Mathmo123 : Except when $F$ is empty, and this is the case.

Comment: I think it can't be that reason because in the same theorem weh have just after this statement : If $card(E)=card(F)$ then a surjective map is bijective (without the condition of $\not = 0$)

Comment: There is no reason to exclude the zero case.

Comment: Perhaps it could be because the proof is invalid in the empty case (The empty case is sufficiently trivial that the author may not have felt the need to prove it)? Does the given proof assume that $E \ne \emptyset$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to do this, but perhaps the reason is because there is a unique map $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, and it is naturally bijective, so there is nothing to say. (If you think of a map $f : E \to F$ as being a subset of the cartesian product $E \times F$ defined by the couples $(e,f(e))$ for $e \in E$, then the graph of the function $\varnothing \to \varnothing$ is simply the empty set.

Edit : Another way to look at it is that the empty set is a subset of every set ("because all its elements are in every set" is vacuously true) so the inclusion map from the empty set to any set exists.

Edit 2 : Even using the theorems in the book you can show that the result is true in the case where $|E|=|F|=0$. Paragraph 4.2 of page 156 says any map $\varnothing \to F$ is injective, and Paragraph 4.4 of page 158 says at the 2) example that any map $\varnothing \to \varnothing$ is bijective. Therefore the (only) map $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, according to the book up to page 158, is injective and bijective.

However, one good reason to exclude the case $|E|=|F|=0$ in the statement of their theorems, is that the proofs they give are not valid in this case. If they wanted to include this case in the theorem, they would have to prove the empty case separately, which they didn't. (I am talking about the proof of 4) at page 171.) The proof goes wrong when they say "suppose $f$ is an injection of $[[1,n]]$ to itself which is not surjective ; thus there exists $y \in [[1,n]]$ such that (...)" and in the empty case this is false.

Hope that helps,

Comment: yes i see that but why the author does not suppose this hypothesis when talking about surjectivity in the same theorem!! The book is in french and it is rather a very well known book in the french mathematical litterature.

Comment: What book is it? (I am a native french speaker, I could look it up.) For me it just seems like an author point-less worry... it happens.

Comment: Chevalier et Oudot - "Maths MPSI, H prepa tout en un" page 172.

Comment: @palio : I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We single it out because there is no function from empty set to itself. Meaningless. I think author should have mentioned it in both cases. I guess he just missed. what book you been reading?

Comment: ...See my answer & comment.

Comment: well yeah, empty to empty, an empty map. But it is like an invisible map. It comes under nothingness. 
"Much ado about nothing"

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned in algebra, it's that trivial cases are important.

Comment: yeah you are right, mate.